# Reflexive, symmetrical but not transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I am supposed to create a relation R on a set $X = \{a,b,c,d\}$ that is reflexive, symmetrical but not transitive.

My attempt looks like this: $R = \{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,d),(a,b)(b,a),(b,c),(c,b),(c,d)(d,c)\}$

I believe my current solution works - but I have also been presented with a *minimal* solution, which would look like this:

$R = \{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,d),(a,b),(b,a),(b,c),(c,b)\}$

It reflexive since $(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,d)\in R$.

I can also see that it is not transitive, since $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in R $ but there is no $(a,c) \in R $.

But is it symmetrical?

The defintion of a symmetrical relationship is as follows:

$\forall x \forall y$ $xRy \implies yRx $

I thought that since the element $d \in X$, I would have to include something like $(d,c)$ and $(c,d)$ in R, in order for it to actually be symmetrical. I interpret the $\forall x \forall y $ as all elements in X, am I missing something really obvious here?

Is it perhaps that $(d,d)\in R$ and if we were to look at $x=d$ and $y=d$, we do in fact have a $xRy \implies yRx$ ?

Comment: I will point out that the empty relation is in fact symmetrical as well.  The relation $R=\emptyset$ is a symmetrical relation on $X$.  The only way that a relation is *not* symmetrical is if there exists some $a,b$ such that $(a,b)\in R$ but $(b,a)\not\in R$.  The absence of any such $a,b$ to be used in the hypothesis does not preclude it from being considered symmetrical.  Don't forget about [vacuous truths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: "I thought that since the element d∈X, I would have to include something like (d,c) and (c,d) in R, in order for it to actually be symmetrical. "  Why?

Comment: A rephrasing of the symmetrical property:  Any pair $(x,y)$ *that happens to be in the relation* must also have its reverse in the relation too.

Comment: @JMoravitz, really helpful, thank you!

Comment: Any $(d,x)$ that exists must have a $(x,d)$ as well.  But there is utterly no reason that any $(d,x); x \ne d$ must be included.

Comment: As an aside, your created example does correctly satisfy all of the desired properties (*apart from being a minimal example*).

Comment: Also as an aside.  If you wanted minimal symmetric and reflexive but don't care whether transitive or not you'd do (a,a),(b,b)(c,c) and (d,d).  You don't need any more.  The only reason we had $(a,b)$ was to make it *not* transitive which requires at least two $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misreading how the quantifiers interact with the implication in the definition of symmetry.

Requiring that $\forall x\forall y(xRy\Rightarrow yRx)$ is the same as requiring that *all of these* 16 instances must be true:
$$ \begin{array}{cccc}
aRa \Rightarrow aRa, & aRb \Rightarrow bRa, & aRc \Rightarrow cRa, & aRd \Rightarrow dRa, \\
bRa \Rightarrow aRb, & bRb \Rightarrow bRb, & bRc \Rightarrow cRb, & bRd \Rightarrow dRb, \\
cRa \Rightarrow aRc, & cRb \Rightarrow bRc, & cRc \Rightarrow cRc, & cRd \Rightarrow dRc, \\
dRa \Rightarrow aRd, & dRb \Rightarrow bRd, & dRc \Rightarrow cRd, & dRd \Rightarrow dRd \\
\end{array}$$

In both of the examples you present, some of these -- such as $aRb\Rightarrow bRa$ -- are true because both sides of the $\Rightarrow$ are true.  Others, such as $dRb\Rightarrow bRd$ are true because both sides are *false*, which is a perfectly good way for a $\Rightarrow$ to be true.

The difference between your example and the minimal example is just that $dRc\Rightarrow cRd$ and $cRd\Rightarrow dRc$ are true for one reason in your example and true for another reason in the minimal example. They're true all the same.

Answer (score 1):

To be symettric if $(d,c)$ is included than $(c,d)$ must also be included.  But there is absolutely no reason $(d,c)$ need to be included$.

To have a minimum relationship that is *not* transitive you need:

Wolog: $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ but *not* $(a,c)$.

To be reflexive you need.  $(a,a), (b,b), (c,c), (d,d)$.

Since you have $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ you need $(b,a)$ and $(c,b)$.  You also need $(a,a), (b,b), (c,c),(d,d)$ but those are "self-symmetric" so to speak and we already listed them.

so $(a,a)(b,b)(c,c)(a,b)(b,a),(a,c),(c,a),(d,d)$ is reflexive symmetric and not reflexive and minimal.

Now if we threw in any $(d,x)$ we would have to throw in $(x,d)$ but there is utterly no reason we have to throw in *any* $(d,x); d\ne x$.

Perhaps it would make things clear if we point out the *ONLY* reason we had to toss it $(a,b)$ in the first place was so that it *couldn't* be transitive.  If we don't have *any* $(x,y); x\ne y$ we *can't* have any $(x,y), (y,z)$ but not $(x,z)$.

If the problem was find a relationship that was reflexive and symmetric and we don't care whether it is or is not transitive, the minimal would be $\{(a,a),(b,b), (c,c),(d,d)\}$.

It's reflexive:  $(x,x)$ is included for all $x$.

It's symmetric:  If $(x,y)$ is included so is $(y,x)$.

But it is also transitive.

To not be transitive we need $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ without $(x,z)$.  (So $x\ne z$ as $(x,x)$ is included.  ANd $z \ne y$ as $(x,y)$ is included and $x \ne y$ as $(y,z)$ is included.)  But we don't need any *more*.

Comment: Since it is specified to be a reflexive relation on $\{a,b,c,d\}$, we need $(d,d)$.

Comment: Ah, okay. Can't argue with "The basic problems says ...."

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A$, $B$ and $C$ non-empty sets. Define the relation "i" as: $A$ is in the relation "i" with $B$ iff $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$. Thus, it is easy to construct examples with $A$i$B$, $B$i$C$ but there is no relation between $A$ and $C$.